# Is $M_n(Z_p)$ a Baer*-ring?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, baer-rings

Let $p$ be a prime number and $n$ be a  natural number. Does $M_n({\mathbf{Z}}_p)$, the ring of all $n\times n$ matrices over the field ${\mathbf{Z}}_p$ form a Baer*-ring?

If not, what about for some special $p$ and $n>2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $R$ is a ring such that $M_n R$ is Baer*, then all sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i r_i^*$ must be nonzero, unless all $r_i = 0$. With *-transpose involution on matrix rings over $R$, this excludes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $n \geq 2$, as well as $p\equiv -1 \pmod 4$ and $n \geq 3$, whenever the characteristic of $R$ is $p$.

Comment: Thanks for your pay attention. Could you please inform me a reference concerning these facts? Does there exist any other type finite  (non-commutative) Baer*ring(s)?

Comment: I don't have access to it right now, but early in Kaplansky's rings of operators monograph, there are results of this type. But for a Baer* ring, it must have $aa* =0$ implies $a= 0$; apply this to a row of size $n$.